# Notifications in Android with firebase. Not stacked

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

AT this moment I achive to get Push Notifications (Firebase) to my client.
I followed the instructions onf firebase.

Now, as the app is a message client, I'm receiving a lot of pushes (meanwhile the app is ni background and foreground).

What I tried (and found here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html)

So my code, right now is:

```
public class FCMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Logger.d("Notification Body:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()
                + "\n DATA:" + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        String jid = remoteMessage.getData().get("jid");
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), jid);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String jid) {


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_chv)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title))
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setGroup(jid);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

AS you can see, I receive in data bundle, the parameter "jid", that identifies the user who send the message. So I use it to try to stak all theis messages, and at the end , have 1 (stacked)notification(s) for every jid.

But, the notifications don't stack when the app is in Background, even more..it launches the notications that where stacked before.

IS there any work around to solve it?

Log of what I receive from notification push:

```
23304-17215 D/ChatListRealmAdapter: ║ Notification Body:Ana ha enviado un mensaje
23304-17215 D/ChatListRealmAdapter: ║  DATA:{'jid':'ana1234@domain.com'}
```